# Need help regarding building logic, adding properties to object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an images array in which there are number of images. Not fixed, may be one or two or 8. When i have fixed number of images then i was using the code something like this

```
var details = {

    image1: {
        position: 0,
        title: $slideDiv.children().eq(0).attr("alt")
    },
    image2: {
        position: -400,
        title: $slideDiv.children().eq(1).attr("alt")
    },
    image3: {
        position: -800,
        title: $slideDiv.children().eq(2).attr("alt")
    },
    image4: {
        position: -1200,
        title: $slideDiv.children().eq(3).attr("alt")
    },
    image5: {
        position: -1600,
        title: $slideDiv.children().eq(4).attr("alt")
    }

}; //end of var details
```

But now i have images in array. I want that details object has added images in it equal to number of images in the array. I tried something like this

```
var details = {};
var position = 0;
images.each(function(index){
    details.("image" + index) : {
        position: position,
        title: $slideDiv.children().eq(index).attr("alt")
    }

    position += -400;

}) ; //end of .each()
```

The logic that i am trying to make is if i have two images in the images array the it should become something like this

```
var details = {
    image1: {
        position: 0,
        title: $slideDiv.children().eq(1).attr("alt")
    },
    image2: {
        position: -400,
        title: $slideDiv.children().eq(2).attr("alt")
    }

}
```

but this is not working. Of course my syntax is wrong

```
details.("image" + index) : {..}
```

How can i do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just make it an array rather than an object with named properties?

Comment: I am building image gallery. when the number of images are fixed then the logic was with the objects. So now i am just trying to make things dynamic rather than static. So i am using the same logic but now all the variables are setting with respect to the number of images in the array

Comment: For clarity purposes, you might want to switch to an array.  Usually you would do the `obj[name]` syntax only in cases where you couldn't predict the name in advance.  Here the names follow such a regular pattern they don't actually tell you anything about specific elements, and just complicate the storage and retrieval of individual elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is: `details['image' + index]` which can later be accessed through `details.image0`, `details.image1` etc.

So it should be: `details['image' + index] = {prop: val}`

Comment: it is not working also `details['image' + index] : {
            position: position,
            title: $slideDiv.children().eq(index).attr("alt")
        }` The error is **missing ; before statement ** on line `details['image' + index] : {`

Comment: It needs to be: `details['image' + index] = {prop: val}`

Comment: I just tried another thing, i want to confirm is that syntax also true? `images.each(function(index){
        details["image" + (index + 1)] = new Object;
        details["image" + (index + 1)].position = position;
        details["image" + (index + 1)].title = $slideDiv.children().eq(index).attr("alt")
 position += -400;
    }) ; //end of .each()` Thanks

Comment: Looks fine except you forgot a `;` before `position += 400`. Don't really see why you'd do that instead of `details['image' + (index + 1)] = {prop: val, prop2: val};` though.

Comment: I tried this just before you tell me the answer and it worked for me :). Anyways thanks for your answer, i tried your answer too and it worked too :). Now i have done what i want. My image gallery is working perfectly :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript you can access a property one of two ways:

```
obj.property
```

is equivalent to

```
obj["property"]
```

So in your case you'll want to write it like this:

```
details["image"+index]
```